# can we write mongodb crud queries and aggregate query together?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In MongoDB can we execute below written query?

```
db.dbaname.find(userName:"abc").aggregate([])
```

else is there any other way we can execute CRUD and aggregate query together.

Comment: Those two are separate functions you can't chain them !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer - No you can't do this : `.find(userName:"abc").aggregate([])`

[aggregation-pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) is heavily used for `reads` which is mostly similar to `.find()` but capable of executing complex queries with help of it's multiple `stages` & many `aggregation-operators`. there are only two stages in aggregation [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/index.html) & [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/index.html) that can perform writes to database - these stages are not that much used compared to other stages & needs to be used only when needed & as they need to be last stages in aggregation pipeline, then all the previous stages are to be tested very well. So when it comes to `CRUD` eliminating `CUD` you'll benefit over `R` - Reads.

Same `.find(userName:"abc")` can be written as :

```
.aggregate( [ { $match : { userName:"abc"} } ] ) // Using `$match` stage
```