# How to get an document in a table and join it with a second table mogodb, Getting Error : .find(...).aggregate is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am working with mongodb and I have two tables, a users and a books one. I want to get an specific user and join it with the second table. Example:

Document Example of table users:

```
var user = {
 _id: ObjectId('asduiasbdiuasbduiasbduib'),
 username: 'raos',
 last_login: '12-01-2020'
}
```

Document Example of table book:

```
var book = {
  _id: ObjectId('jkngsjilsdhioh'),
  bookTitle: 'Lost in space',
  available: false,
  rented_by:  'asduiasbdiuasbduiasbduib'
}
```

I tried the next thing:

```
F.db.collection('users').find({_id: 'asduiasbdiuasbduiasbduib'}).aggregate([
    {
        $lookup:{
            from: 'books',
            localField: '_id',
            foreignField: 'rented_by',
            as: 'books'

        }
    }
]).toArray((err, res) => {
    console.log(res);
});
// Error showed:
//F.db.collection(...).find(...).aggregate is not a function
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can we write mongodb crud queries and aggregate query together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62108983/can-we-write-mongodb-crud-queries-and-aggregate-query-together)

Answer (score 0):

```
function something(userId) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var aggregate = user.aggregate();
    aggregate
      .match({
        _id: ObjectId(userId)
      })
      .lookup({
        localField: '_id',
        from: 'books',
        foreignField: 'rented_by',
        as: 'book'
      })
    aggregate.exec(function (err, books) {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      return resolve(books);
    });
  });
}
```

Does it solved your problem?